# Web UI for Gearman or Alternatives for PHP Job Queue

Tags: php, gearman

We develop a suite of PHP SASS applications and we use Gearman to process tasks in the background both synchronously and asynchronously. We love everything Gearman has to offer but we've beginning to find the administration of the queue to becoming tedious.

Has anyone here had experience with a Web UI for Gearman that allows you to see all job servers and jobs queued on them?

Or any suggestion for alternative to Gearman that will run easily on LAMP stack and has good PHP library support, and a Web UI ofcause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [`gearman-stat.psgi`](https://github.com/tokuhirom/gearman-stat.psgi/blob/master/gearman-stat.psgi). A small Perl script build upon [Plack](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Plack) which makes it very easy to run this script as a stand-alone HTTP server, CGI or FCGI script, as well as mod_perl. Even if you don't want to use it you can take a look at the source code to see how it is fetching statistics.

Comment: I ended up following a link in the readme to the apache_mod mod_gearman_status https://github.com/amir/mod_gearman_status

Comment: If you're using Apache than that's a great solution. You might also want to keep track of http://www.gearmanhq.com/, a hosted solution for Gearman (seemingly to be nearing beta soon) with metrics and what not. Also, the Gearman protocol is defined here http://gearman.org/index.php?id=protocol if you want to talk to it directly by yourself (see Administrative Protocol).

Answer (score 6):

I've just published a new Gearman UI. It is sort of an updated version of Gearman Monitor, built on AngularJS and Silex: [Gearman UI](https://github.com/gaspaio/gearmanui).

I hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

there is a recommended tool taken from the gearman website : https://github.com/yugene/Gearman-Monitor